# Oracle text search for ranges

Tags: oracle, text, oracle-text

I'm looking for a better way of searching through numeric ranges in Oracle Text. I have a DB app that does a lot of GIS-type things, but we now want to add street range searching to it.

So I'd like to store the min and max values in a column, and search for a number within those values. I'm happy to go explore options, but I'd like some pointers on where to head. Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

EDIT: we're just trying to make address lookups easier. Text on the address parts has been a huge success, but we want to store street ranges instead of every individual house number. 
So, if I searched for "11 high street", I'd expect a match if high street had a range of 1 to 1000. I'd also like some options that I can use if I searched for "flat 1 11 high street" too though. I expect that I will have to do some jiggery with the input in these cases, I just want to know what kind of tools there are that I could try working with.

Comment: Can you give more details about the setup. What is your address format and are you actually attaching spatial co-ordinates to it. My initial feeling is, rather than street number ranges, you'll need a box or line geometry and see if there is an intersection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to make standard length string field for storing building numbers, create index on this field and then use `between` for search.

Something like this format:

```
NNNNNNCCCCBBBB
```

where:

`NNNNNN` - left-padded house number;
  `CCCC`   - left-padded character (like 'A' in '11A');
  `BBBB`   - left-padded building number

Under 'left-padded' I mean "filled with some symbol to standard length at left side", see for example result of `select lpad('11',5,'X') from dual;` query.

E.g. suppose, you have "11A high street building 5" address and choose '%' as filling symbol. When converted to proposed format it looks like `'%%%11%%%A%%%'` and 'high street' stored at separated field(s).
Next is query example for selecting all houses between 1 and 1000:

```
with address_list as (
  select '%%%11%%%A%%%%' bnum from dual union all
  select '%1001%%%A%%%%' bnum from dual union all
  select '%%%%1%%%A%%%%' bnum from dual union all
  select '%%%%1%%%%%%%%' bnum from dual union all
  select '%%321%%%A%%%%' bnum from dual union all
  select '%1000%%%A%%%%' bnum from dual union all
  select '%1000%%QQ%%12' bnum from dual 
)
select * from address_list
where 
  -- from '1 high street'
  bnum >= '%%%%1%%%%%%%%' 
  and                    
  -- less then '1001 high street'            
  bnum < '%1001%%%%%%%%' 
order by 
  bnum
```

In real case is better to use `chr(1)` or any other unprintable symbol as symbol for padding.

Another thing is to build only function-based index for search without real field storage.

Answer (score 2):

Anything wrong with

```
WHERE <number> BETWEEN minColumn AND maxColumn
```

Comment: Often street numbers aren't (numbers that is). I live at number 11, and the house next to me is 11A.

Comment: 11A is a number.. 11A is just hex for 282 bro